Construction of a big line bundle on the total space from the base and the fiber
Let $g: X\to S$ be a proper morphism of analytic space, assume that there exists a big line bundle on $S$ denote it $L_1$ and a $g$-big line bundle $L_2$ defined on $X$, can we construct an (absolute) big line bundle on $X$?)

I know the similar result for ample line bundle (and Kahler form). That is if $L_1$ is an ample line bundle on $S$ and $L_2$ is an $g$-ample line bundle defined on $X$, then $$Cg^* L_1 + L_2,\quad C \gg 0$$is an ample line bundle. (The proof can use the relative version of the Kleiman's ampleness criterion)
If we replace ample with a big line bundle can we construct some (absolute) big line bundle on $X$ similarly?

The motivation of this question is the following fact: Let $g:X\to S$ be a proper morphism between complex analytic space, $S$ is Moishezon then $g$ is Moishezon iff $X$ is Moishezon. And I was trying to prove this. I also know a analog result which says if the fiber is of general type and the base is of general type then the total space is of general type. (Some special case of the Iitaka conjecture, the proof require some hyperbolicity). I guess the question that I ask is not that complicated? I try to use the Kodaira lemma the big divisor can be written as the ample + effective and the question reduce to deal with the effective divisor.

What you've written here in the comments is a good addition to the post, so I put it there for you. In the future, when you have additions like this, please place them in the main post, not the comments - comments are much more temporary than additions to the post.

Ok thank you KReiser.

The answer to your question is yes. I will give a modified version of the argument to the one found at the bottom of page 4 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511042
Let $B$ be big line bundle on $S$ and $D$ a $g$-big line bundle on $X$. Pick an ample line bundle $H$ on $X$. Since $D$ is $g$-big, we can pick $m$ large enough that $g_*(mD - H) \neq 0$. I will elaborate on this point a bit. Let $\eta$ be the generic point of $S$. Then $B_{X_\eta}$ is big by the definition of $g$-big. Therefore $h^0(X_\eta, mB_{X_\eta} - H_{X_\eta}) > 0$ by Kodaira's lemma. Then semicontinuity + Grauert's theorem says that $g_*(mD - H)$ will be a vector bundle of rank $h^0(X_\eta, mB_{X_\eta} - H_{X_\eta})$ on an open subset of $S$, so $g_*(mD - H) \neq 0$.
Since $B$ is big, we can pick $k$ large enough so that $g_*(mD - H) + kB$ has a section (you can use Kodaira's lemma to prove this as well). By the projection formula, this implies that $mD-H+ kg^*B$ has a section, therefore, $E = mD-H+ kg^*B$ is effective. Rearranging, we get that $mD+kg^*B = H+E$ and so $mD+kg^*B$ is big by Kodaira's Lemma.
If we let $C = k/m$ then we get that $D + Cg^*B$ is big. In the proof, we can choose $k$ to be as large as we want, so $D + Cg^*B$ will be big for all $C\gg 0$.

Thank you @Brian Nugent , I also noticed this wonderful paper yesterday, and trying to use the idea in the paper. very thanks for your help.
